# Why does 1px in CSS not match with 1 px from screen resolution?

Tags: html, css

If you inspect body/html of this site (or any else) from dev tools you can clearly see width (x) of the **page are 15-20% smaller** compared to your **screen resolution**.

[image]

**Where the difference come from ?**

I understand why there could be a small differences +-50px coz of borders/scrollbars etc. of browser itself, but I'm sure they aren't 400 missing px wide.

I also checked if my browser settings is set to 100% scale

[image]

Comment: Because screen resolution does not match CSS px. CSS px is always the same size, no matter what kind of display you have

Comment: “[The term CSS pixel is synonymous with the CSS unit of absolute length `px` — which is normatively defined as being exactly 1/96th of 1 inch.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_pixel)”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Calculated Sizes

It's pretty common these days to have calculated sizes, clamps, or min/max definitions. So, first thing to check is whether these are affecting the numbers you expect.

## Pixel Density

Modern devices have different screen densities. Basically, this means more physical blinky lights are used to represent one "theoretical pixel", which allows for super high resolution rendering.

Mathmatecially, there will be a ratio of real pixels (blinky lights) to theoretical pixels, for example the iPhone 11 Pro has a 3x pixel density, and the Samsung Galaxy S10 has a 4x pixel density. This is "how many device pixels there are for each CSS pixel.

To look at this another way, the 1440 physical pixels on the Samsung represents 360 CSS pixels.

A full rundown is available [in this article](https://elad.medium.com/understanding-the-difference-between-css-resolution-and-device-resolution-28acae23da0b).